# Why does pip on Amazon Linux 2 download lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz, while it downloads lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl on Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, python-poetry

> Why does pip on Amazon Linux 2 download lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz, while it downloads lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_aarch64.whl on Amazon Linux 2023?

I need to download and install the `manylinux` variant, as the former doesn't work on AWS Lambda, yielding the following error:

```
"Unable to import module 'app.dim.application.watchdog': libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

Why does `pip` (`python@3.11.2`) download the`manylinux` variant, while `pip` (`python@3.11.4`) download the source package?

What's the difference between these packages, and why does the `manylinux` variant work in AWS Lambda, while the source package doesn't (both create a wheel)?

Answer (score 0):

`lxml` python package might not create a wheel that supports amazon linux 2 anymore. (See it's [PyPi download files](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files) to confirm).

The platform tags mappings to distros is detailed in [pypa/manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux#manylinux) git repo.

Amazon Linux 2 is based on CentOS 7 distro and only supports pypa platform tags of `manylinux2014`. Amazon Linux 2023 is based on newer versions of Fedora and CentOS and thus can support `manylinux_2_28` (a newer tag). So that could explain why the source is downloaded for amazon linux 2 and the wheel is downloaded for amazon linux 2023.